Is it possible to remove existing submodule?
I need to modify existing submodule of switch, which located in application layer.
I tried to inherit this submodule, but there is error: handleRegisterProtocol(): protocol is already registered.
I need only idea how to realize it.
Thanks in advance!
I tried deletemodule() but it cause instant end of simulation.
I also tried disconnect() all gates of original submodule but there is no effect.
